# XPATH in Selenium IDE: Matching text in a <td> tag that contains <br> tags

Tags: selenium, text, xpath, tags, match

For the following HTML:

```
<td class="td1">
<div class="dv1">
LINE_ONE<br>
LINE_TWO<br>
LINE_THREE<br>
</div>
</td>
```

We can match LINE_ONE with this xpath --> //td[@class='td1']/div[@class='dv1'  and contains(text(),' LINE_ONE')].

We can NOT match LINE_TWO with this xpath --> //td[@class='td1']/div[@class='dv1'  and contains(text(),' LINE_TWO')].

The BR tag is running interference. The Selenium IDE 'Select' feature can grab the DIV tag xpath but can't go any deeper into the text that it contains.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace `text()` with `.` :

```
//td[@class='td1']/div[@class='dv1' and contains(.,'LINE_TWO')]
```

While `text()` only returns the first descendant text node in this particular usage scenario, `.` returns concatenation of all descendant text nodes

Comment: For completion's sake: all lines get concatenated by single space character.